# Launch Bash console when logging into windows account

Tags: windows, bash, unix

I'm looking for the bash console to automatically launch when I sign into my windows account on my laptop for easier navigation, etc. What do I have to do to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a .bat script and adding it to the StartUp Folder:

1. Press `win+r`
2. Enter`shell:startup`
3. Make a .bat file with the commands to want to execute at startup

Example .bat:

```
@echo off
calc
```